# How to reuse style with two different bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-style

I have this `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="BlinkStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BlinkForError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type loc:DevicesRepositoryEditorUserControl}}}"
                     Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="BlinkBeginStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:0.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BlinkBeginStoryboard" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Whenever the bound dependency-property `BlinkForError` is set to `True`, it start blinking. It works great, like this:

```
<!-- When BlinkForError set to True, this TextBox, named "One", blinks: -->
<TextBox Name="One" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BlinkStyle}"/>
```

Thing is that I want exactly the same thing, but bound to another dependency-property, say `AnotherBlinkForError`:

```
<!-- When AnotherBlinkForError set to True, this TextBox, named "Two", blinks: -->
<TextBox Name="Two" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AnotherBlinkStyle}"/>
```

I can duplicate the whole style and only change the `DataTrigger`'s `Binding` part.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication, reuse the same `Style` twice with two different bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and make use of the `Tag` properties on your `TextBoxes` and bind them to the `BlinkForError` and `BlinkForAnotherError`. In your style definition the binding will check the `Tag` value (you'd probably have to use `RelativeSource` and `FindAncestor` options) instead of the Blink properties.

But to be honest, if there are only two `TextBoxes` and respective error properties I would go with two separate styles as it's just less hassle.

Comment: What about `<DataTrigger Binding="{RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}}" Value="True" />`?